# How to make libCurl use hexadecimal cnonce instead of alphanumeric in Digest authentication header

Tags: c, libcurl, digest-authentication

I have recently started using libCurl for client-server communication project where I use libcurl in the client side. We used to use WinHTTP, but did not find a way to add TLS 1.3 backward compatibility with earlier windows versions.

The cnonce is part of Digest Authentication headers.

When my project was earier using WinHTTP, the cnonce used to be hexadecimal.
Eg:

```
cnonce="a01e21c2a827ec6d3d9b6e1745ca8a0b"
```

**HTTP Header**

Server to client:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 26
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="a2ffc77914d6e791d", qop="auth",nonce="3f3da4b94e249058", opaque ="3b3542c"
```

Client to Server:

```
POST /wsman HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Openwsman
Content-Length: 889
Host: 10.138.141.178:623
Authorization: Digest username="PostMan",realm="a2ffc77914d6e791d",nonce="3f3da4b94e249058",uri="/wsman",cnonce="a01e21c2a827ec6d3d9b6e1745ca8a0b",nc=00000001,response="9dd37ef997ef332e46dff0f868b3de89",qop="auth",opaque="3b3542c"
```

When I look at the HTTP header I find that the cnonce is alphanumeric with Curl.
Eg:

```
cnonce="NDlmYTM0ZjVlM2IzNTNhMDNiNDk0MzQ1MzdlYmFlMzA="
```

**HTTP Header**

Server to Client

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="a2ffc77914d6e791d", nonce="5bf1156647e8eb42", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth", opaque="661d9eae", userhash=true
```

Client to Server

```
POST /wsman HTTP/1.1
Host: blr-5cg64728l6.amd.com:623
Authorization: Digest username="PostMan", realm="a2ffc77914d6e791d", nonce="5bf1156647e8eb42", uri="/wsman", cnonce="NDlmYTM0ZjVlM2IzNTNhMDNiNDk0MzQ1MzdlYmFlMzA=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="6847e465c9c90b40264b736070f721da", opaque="661d9eae", algorithm=MD5, userhash=true
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Openwsman
Content-Length: 897
```

With alpha numeric cnonce the server is not responding back consistantly. Is there a way to specify in libcurl to generate hexadecimal cnonce - explicitly?

Note: To avoid security risk, the fields have been modified in the headers above.

I am using LibCurl: 7.73
with OpenSSL TLS backend: 1.1.1h

Comment: That "alphanumeric" looks like a base64 encoded value to me. cURL has built-in support to decode that. But maybe you can post the full HTTP headers of both requests.

Comment: Adding @bagder, adding you in case you know a solution

Comment: And how are you generating the request? Where's your code?

Comment: I currently don't have minimum shareable version, because the code is too large to separate out the authentication part